# Wordpress site show white screen after updating some plugins (URGENT)

Tags: plugins

I updated some plugins and few minutes later when i check my site i see white screen.

What i tried:

I reboot server
I loaded a backup from what i before
I change the name of plugins directory to plugins2
I added debug true in wp-config.php

Stil only white screen.

Please help this is urgent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your emails: a white screen should make Wordpress send you an email saying there’s a critical problem and inviting you to fix it.

Could caching be stopping wp_debug from working yet? (Clear cache)

If renaming plugins folder doesn’t work, try moving the current theme directory out of the /themes folder. Ensure the /twentytwenty theme is in the /themes folder so that it defaults to that.

Do you have a backup of the database?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to FTP?

If yes, go to public_html/wp-content/plugins and copy to your local drive the folders of plugins you updated recently.
Later, delete of the ftp one folder plugin each time, and test if the website works. If it still doesnt work, try deleting another folder...

Comment: Instead of deleting the folders just add -disabled to the name.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend to check the error_log on your server, usually (cPanel env.) you find it right in the root of the website, if not just check for the logs area.
After you find the culprit, go via FTP/SFTP and rename the plugin that causes the trouble.

Another good approach is to go via FTP/SFTP in root(public_html)/wp-content(folder) and rename the plugins folder. This way all the plugins get disabled.

After you manage to log in, rename the plugins folder back to "plugins" so you can restore the plugins (all deactivated) then just activate one by one till you find the culprit.